# Expressing logical conjunction with logical imlication and equivalence.

Tags: logic

I've come across an exercise which requires you to express every one of the logical operators $\{\wedge, \Rightarrow, \Leftrightarrow\}$ with the other two - for example,
$$p \Leftrightarrow q \sim (p \Rightarrow q) \wedge (q \Rightarrow p).$$
So far I've only been able to do this with $\Leftrightarrow$, which is straightforward enough, but now I'm stuck.
I don't think I'm allowed to use constants such as '0' or '1'. Is this even possible? Any help (tips or a solution) would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: ok I found the solution for $\wedge$:

$$p \wedge q \sim (p \Leftrightarrow q)\Leftrightarrow ((p \Leftrightarrow q)\Rightarrow p)$$

Comment: A shorter solution for $\land$: $(p\implies q)\iff p$

Answer (score 2):

I think that works:

$$p\Rightarrow q \sim p\wedge q \Leftrightarrow p\\
p\wedge q\sim (p\Rightarrow q)\Leftrightarrow (q\Rightarrow p)$$

(You can check truth tables)

Comment: The first one seems correct, but the second one doesn't (for example, if $p=q=0$). Still, thanks for your answer.